# Verificação para Data Table

Tags: php, mysql, datatable

Estou utilizando Data Table para fazer uma table de dominios/subdominios e alguns acessos, como a minha tabela é um pouco grande tive de utilizar Child rows, a minha preocupação e fazer a validação, quero validar, como mostra a imagem, caso tenha introduzino na BD pass e email do back ofice mostra a linha com as informações, caso os campos estejas vazios, nao mostra nada.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function format ( d ) {
        // `d` is the original data object for the row
        return '<table class="new" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="background:white; float:left; border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 0 8px; margin-top: -8px;border:none; margin-left:30px;">'+
            '<tr style="background:white">'+
                '<td style="border:none"><b>Email Back Office: &nbsp;</b></td>'+
                '<td style="border:none"> <input style="border: none; outline:none" readonly name="mail" id="mail" value="'+d.email+'"> <button style="background: aliceblue; border: 1px solid cadetblue;" title="Copiar Email" onclick="myFunction()"><i class="fas fa-copy"></i></button></td>'+
            '</tr>'+
            '<tr style="background:white">'+
                '<td style="border:none"><b> Password Back Office: &nbsp; </b> </td>'+
                '<td style="border:none"> <input style="border: none; outline:none" readonly name="pw" id="pw" value="'+d.pass+'"> <button style="background: aliceblue; border: 1px solid cadetblue;" title="Copiar Password" onclick="myFunctionPass()"><i class="fas fa-copy"></i></button></td>'+
            '</tr>'+
            '</table>' 
        ;
    }


$(document).ready( function () {
   var users =  $('#myTable').DataTable( {
            "columns": [
                { "data": "" },
                { "data": "dominio" },
                { "data": "subdominio" },
                { "data": "certificado" },
                { "data": "registo" },
                { "data": "data" },
                { "data": "qtd" },
                { "data": "preco"} ,
                { "data": "comentarios" },
                { "data": "email" },
                { "data": "pass" },
                { "data": "opcoes" },
    ],
    "order": [[1, 'asc']],
    responsive: true,
    "lengthMenu": [[14, 50, 100, -1], [14, 50, 100, "Todos"]],
    "language": {
        "sEmptyTable": "Nenhum registro encontrado",
        "sInfo": "_START_ / _END_ de _TOTAL_ registros",
        "sInfoEmpty": " 0 / 0 de 0 registros",
        "sInfoFiltered": "(Filtrados de _MAX_ registros)",
        "sInfoPostFix": "",
        "sInfoThousands": ".",
        "sLengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registos por página",
        "sLoadingRecords": "Carregar...",
        "sProcessing": "Processar...",
        "sZeroRecords": "Nenhum registro encontrado!",
        "sSearch": "",
        "searchPlaceholder": "Pesquisar...",
        "oPaginate": {
            "sNext": "Próximo",
            "sPrevious": "Anterior",
            "sFirst": "Primeiro",    
            "sLast": "Último"
        },
    }
});

$('#search').keyup(function() {
    users.search($(this).val()).draw();
})

$('#myTable tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var row = users.row( tr );

    if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
        row.child.hide();
        tr.removeClass('shown');
    }else {
        row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();
        tr.addClass('shown');
    }
});
```

});

E eu nao sei como vou fazer a validação para isso acontecer, todos os campos da tabela estao guardados na base de dados.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvido!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function format ( d ) {
        // `d` is the original data object for the row
        if(d.email != ""){
            return '<table class="new" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="background:white; float:left; border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 0 8px; margin-top: -8px;border:none; margin-left:30px;">'+
                '<tr style="background:white">'+
                    '<td style="border:none"><b>Email Back Office: &nbsp;</b></td>'+
                    '<td style="border:none"> <input style="border: none; outline:none" readonly name="mail" id="mail" value="'+d.email+'"> <button style="background: aliceblue; border: 1px solid cadetblue;" title="Copiar Email" onclick="myFunction()"><i class="fas fa-copy"></i></button></td>'+
                '</tr>'+
                '<tr style="background:white">'+
                    '<td style="border:none"><b> Password Back Office: &nbsp; </b> </td>'+
                    '<td style="border:none"> <input style="border: none; outline:none" readonly name="pw" id="pw" value="'+d.pass+'"> <button style="background: aliceblue; border: 1px solid cadetblue;" title="Copiar Password" onclick="myFunctionPass()"><i class="fas fa-copy"></i></button></td>'+
                '</tr>'+
                '</table>' 
            ;
        }else {
            return '<p style="font-size: 13px; margin: 0 20px 0px;"> <b> Não Existem Dados Adicionais! </b> </p>'
        }       
    }
```

Efetuei assim a validação, através do parâmetro de entrada